# VBA How to insert multiple rows with value assigned

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert multiple rows with values and formulas assigned in many different tables in excel by using VBA, currently I did something like this, but it results in very slow execution speed:

```
Set t = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
Set t2 = Sheets("sheet2").ListObjects("table2")
Set t3 = Sheets("sheet3").ListObjects("table3")
Set t4 = Sheets("sheet4").ListObjects("table4")
Set t5 = Sheets("sheet5").ListObjects("table5")

    
For Each Cell In component_table_range
    If Cell.Value = Lookup_Value Then
        product_name = Cell.Offset(, 1).Value
        product_type = Cell.Offset(, 2).Value
        product_color = Cell.Offset(, 3).Value
        product_unit = Cell.Offset(, 4).Value
        product_comp = Cell.Offset(, 5).Value
        comp_ref = Cell.Offset(, 6).Value
        comp_name = Cell.Offset(, 7).Value
        comp_type = Cell.Offset(, 8).Value
        comp_color = Cell.Offset(, 9).Value
        comp_unit = Cell.Offset(, 10).Value
        comp_amount = Cell.Offset(, 11).Value
      
    Set lrRow = t.ListRows.Add
    With lrRow
        .Range(1) = ref
        .Range(2) = Lookup_Value
        .Range(3) = product_name
        .Range(4) = product_type
        .Range(5) = product_color
        .Range(6) = product_unit
        .Range(7) = order_amount
        .Range(8) = product_comp
        .Range(9) = comp_ref
        .Range(10) = comp_name
        .Range(11) = comp_unit
        .Range(12) = comp_amount
        .Range(13).Formula = "=Indirect(""G"" & Row()) * Indirect(""L"" & Row())"
        .Range(14).Formula = "=Indirect(""Q"" & Row()) + Indirect(""U"" & Row()) + Indirect(""Y"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AC"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AG"" & Row())"
        .Range(15).Formula = "=Indirect(""N"" & Row()) / Indirect(""M"" & Row()) * 100%"
    End With
    
    Set lrRow2 = t2.ListRows.Add
    With lrRow2
        .Range(1) = ref
        .Range(2) = comp_ref
        .Range(3) = comp_name
        .Range(4).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 13, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(5).Formula = "=Indirect(""I"" & Row()) + Indirect(""P"" & Row()) + Indirect(""W"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AD"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AK"" & Row())"
        .Range(6).Formula = "=Indirect(""K"" & Row()) + Indirect(""R"" & Row()) + Indirect(""Y"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AF"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AM"" & Row())"
        .Range(7).Formula = "=Indirect(""F"" & Row()) / Indirect(""D"" & Row()) * 100%"
        .Range(8).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 16, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(9).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 17, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(15).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 20, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(16).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 21, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(22).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 24, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(23).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 25, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(29).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 28, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(30).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 29, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(36).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 32, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(37).Formula = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 33, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
    End With
    
    Set lrRow3 = t3.ListRows.Add
    With lrRow3
        .Range(1) = ref
        .Range(2) = comp_ref
        .Range(3) = comp_name
        .Range(4) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 13, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(5) = "=Indirect(""H"" & Row()) + Indirect(""L"" & Row()) + Indirect(""P"" & Row()) + Indirect(""T"" & Row()) + Indirect(""X"" & Row())"
        .Range(6) = "=Indirect(""E"" & Row()) / Indirect(""D"" & Row()) * 100%"
        .Range(7) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 8, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(8) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 11, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(11) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 15, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(12) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 18, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(15) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 22, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(16) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 25, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(19) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 29, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(20) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 32, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(23) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 36, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(24) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 39, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
    End With
    
    Set lrRow4 = t4.ListRows.Add
    With lrRow4
        .Range(1) = ref
        .Range(2) = comp_ref
        .Range(3) = comp_name
        .Range(4) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 13, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 9)"
        .Range(5) = "=Indirect(""H"" & Row()) + Indirect(""M"" & Row()) + Indirect(""R"" & Row()) + Indirect(""W"" & Row()) + Indirect(""AB"" & Row())"
        .Range(6) = "=Indirect(""E"" & Row()) / Indirect(""D"" & Row()) * 100%"
        .Range(7) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 7, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(9) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 12, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(12) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 11, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(14) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 19, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(17) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 15, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(19) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 26, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(22) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 19, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(24) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 33, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(27) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 7, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
        .Range(29) = "=ParameterVlookup(table1, 40, Indirect(""A"" & Row()), Indirect(""B"" & Row()), 1, 2)"
    End With
    

End If
```

How could I deal with it with faster execution speed? I tried to remove the formula with raw   values, but it does not improve any. So I don't think it is the vlookup and looup functions make it slow.

Comment: Side note: `INDIRECT` is volatile. Excessive use of it will bog down the worksheet... it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @BigBen Then how could I get the value on the same row even if the row's order is sorted or the value is modified?

Comment: `INDEX` should work, e.g. `INDEX(A:A,ROW())`. Or, is column A part of the table? If so, use structured references.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry I am a bit new to vba, yes, it is a part of table, what is a structured reference? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Comment: @BigBen Thanks a lot! By the way, do you have any ideas about why the above code is executing very slow?

Comment: Because reading/writing cell-by-cell is slow.

Comment: @BigBen Is there another approach to insert a new row instead of cell by cell?

Comment: Whenever possible, you should work with arrays, see [Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx). Also, disabling screenupdating and calculation might help.